# js console.log json object could not get value by key

Tags: javascript, json, console.log

This is My JavaScript code: a simple demo of **Qweb** template

```
<script src="./static/lib/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="qweb2.js"></script>

<script>
    QWeb = new QWeb2.Engine();
    QWeb.add_template('test.xml');

    console.log(QWeb);
    console.log(QWeb.templates);
    console.log('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa');

</script>
```

And here is the result in chrome console:

[image]

Why is `console.log(Qweb.templates)` returning an empty object?

Comment: I can not explain this issue;  Js is so strange;

Comment: Can you recreate it in codepen or somewhere?

Comment: Please refer to [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays) about the behavior of "console.log" in Chrome

Comment: [Here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0gdkrud8/) that demonstrates something similar. `QWeb.add_template()` is asynchronous so it takes a bit of time before `Qweb.templates` is populated.